How to simultaneously send multiple video files (at least 2) using multithreading i.e., pthread library
I have two files one is sender.c and the other is receiver.c file.I am trying to send three video files through pipe.
Here is sender.c file requirement:

The following are the sender’s requirements:

Able to open and read the contents of multiple video files
Create segments and send them over the shared pipes
Indicate the end of the file to the receiver
Close the pipe once the complete file is sent.


Here is receiver.c file requirement:


Able to open new video files
Receive segments from the sender via different threads and write them to new files
Able to identify eof to terminate for each file transfer
Smoothly terminate the thread, close the file and pipe as well.


The problem is that new files are being created but videos are not received properly .Only one video out of three is transferred but distorted.
This is sender.c file code
char *videoFiles[NUM_THREADS] = {"KungFuPanda.mp4", "flowerVideo.mp4","Flower2.mp4"}; // Adjust file names as needed

    // Create threads for each video file
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sendVideo, (void *)videoFiles[i]);
    }

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("All video files sent successfully!\n");
void *sendVideo(void *filename) {
    // Variables
    int p_fd, n;
    char *fileName = (char *)filename;
    FILE *videoFile;

    // Initialization of file pointer
    videoFile = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (videoFile == NULL) {
        printf("File not found: %s\n", fileName);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    // Open pipe for writing
    p_fd = open("videoPipe", O_WRONLY);
    if (p_fd == -1) {
        perror("Error opening pipe");
        fclose(videoFile);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    // Allocate a buffer to read the file contents
    char buffer[CHUNK_SIZE];

    // Read and send file contents in chunks
    size_t bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, CHUNK_SIZE, videoFile)) > 0) {
        // Write file chunk to the pipe
        n = write(p_fd, buffer, bytesRead);
        if (n == -1) {
            perror("Error writing to pipe");
            fclose(videoFile);
            close(p_fd);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    }

    // Send EOF signal by writing 0 bytes
    n = write(p_fd, "", 0);
    if (n == -1) {
        perror("Error writing EOF signal");
        fclose(videoFile);
        close(p_fd);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    // Close file and pipe
    fclose(videoFile);
    close(p_fd);

    printf("Video file %s sent successfully!\n", fileName);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


This is receiver.c file
 for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        // Create a new file to write received data
        char filename[20];
        snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "received_file_%d.mp4", i);
        receivedFiles[i] = fopen(filename, "wb");
        if (receivedFiles[i] == NULL) {
            perror("Error creating file");
            close(p_fd);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    while (1) {
        // Read from the pipe
        n = read(p_fd, buffer, CHUNK_SIZE);
        if (n == -1) {
            perror("Error reading from pipe");
            break;
        } else if (n == 0) { // End of file reached
            break;
        }

        // Write received data to the files
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
            fwrite(buffer, 1, n, receivedFiles[i]);
        }
    }

    // Close the pipe and files
    close(p_fd);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        fclose(receivedFiles[i]);
    }



Are all the thread using the same pipe?

You need ”rb” when opening the file for input.

n = write(p_fd, buffer, bytesRead);?  And what happens when this doesn't write all of bytesRead?

And writing zero bytes doesn’t send an EOF signal. It doesn’t send anything at all. However this part of your requirement is redundant and should be deleted.

You seem to be using a single named pipe for all the data transfer.  In that case, how do you imagine the receiver is going to know to which file to attribute each byte it reads?

yes all threads are using same pipe

So how do you imagine the receiver is going to know how to distribute the bytes it receives among the files being transferred?  This is a rhetorical question, of course, pointing out that (1) right now, it does not know, and (2) you need to think up a mechanism for that.  Just pushing all the raw bytes across the pipe is not sufficient.  I presume that dealing with this is one of the main points of the exercise, so I'll stop there.

Your requirement for sender.c clearly states "send them over the shared pipes." So you are doing it wrong from the bottom up.
